# admin-on-rest: customizing Edit component

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I need to customize `Edit` component in two ways:

- Add custom button, but not to the upper panel (with 'List' and
  'Refresh' buttons), but at the bottom of the component (next to the default 'Save'
  button).
- Turn off redirect on default 'Save' button click (to make it just
  save and stay on page).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Both will be easy to do in the upcoming 1.2.0 version (see the #692 Pull Request on the subject: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/692). In the meantime, you'll have top copy and paste the current Edit component to add your own button, and to create a custom saga to modify the redirection behavior. Since it's quite hard to do, and since 1.2.0 is not far, I advise you to wait ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for 1.2.0.

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto now that 1.2 has been released can you provide the answer to this question. I do not want to create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross this unanswered question. Since I just did something like this very recently myself I will share how I did it here. I am using admin on rest 1.4.0 btw.

So, on your `<Edit>` component, add this `toolbar={<MyCustomToolbar />}`. Then create a custom toolbar with your buttons in it. On the button you can use `redirect` to redirect to another page.

**Code example:**

```
import { SaveButton, Toolbar, TextInput, Edit, SimpleForm  } from 'admin-on-rest';

const MyToolbar = props => 
 <Toolbar {...props} >
   <SaveButton label="Save & to dashboard" redirect="/" />
   .. more buttons here..
 </Toolbar>;


export const EditForm = (props) => (
<Edit title="Edit" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm toolbar={<MyToolbar />}>
        <TextInput source="company_website" type="url" />
        <TextInput source="address_street" />
        <TextInput source="address_zip" />
        <TextInput source="address_unitnr" />
        <TextInput source="address_city" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

Hope this helps!